# How to prevent minimizing parent window from closing child window

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

Good day,

I would like to check if someone can assist with the following problem that I am having. I have a child form displayed using `ShowDialog(this)`, and I am registering to the `Resize` event so that I can change the state of the parent along with the child. The problem is that when the parent form is minimized, the child form closes. I have determined that `WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized` call in the parent causes the `using` statement to pass the blocking call of `ShowDialog(IWin32Window)`, yet I don't understand that when only the child minimizes (and the parent is then unable to gain focus), the blocking call does not get passed. How do I get around this behavior? Preferably without holding a reference to the child window and checking it every time the parent's `WindowState` changes.

My code:

```
private void StockTakeHistoryMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StockTakeWindow window = new StockTakeWindow())
    {
        window.Resize += this.ChildStateChanging;
        window.ShowDialog(this);
        window.Resize -= this.ChildStateChanging;
    }
}

private void ChildStateChanging(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch ((sender as Form).WindowState)
    {
        case FormWindowState.Normal:
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            break;

        case FormWindowState.Minimized:
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            break;

        case FormWindowState.Maximized:
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't prevent the child from closing, you must prevent the parent from minimizing.  The user can't do this, the parent is disabled, so you'll have to find the statement in your code that does it.  Maybe it is in ChildStateChanging(), you must ensure that the child window doesn't allow the user to minimize it.  Set its MinimizeBox property to False.

Comment: And consider whether you really need ShowDialog().  You don't use its return value, don't use *using* and don't retrieve dialog properties so it doesn't look like it.  So good odds that you prefer using Show(), with the FormClosing event to know that the window is about to be closed.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't use the DialogResult, yes, and the using and the ChildStateChanging is implemented as desired. The thing is _I wanted to minimize the parent when the child is minimized_. I wanted to allow for the parent to also be minimized when the user minimize the child so that they can work behind the form even though the parent is disabled as you cant click the minimize when the ShowDialog is still active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
private void ChildStateChanging(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Show();

    switch ((sender as Form).WindowState)
    {
        case FormWindowState.Normal:
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            break;

        case FormWindowState.Minimized:
            //this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            this.Hide();
            break;

        case FormWindowState.Maximized:
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            break;
    }
}
```

I call `this.Show();` call in first of `ChildStateChanging` and I wrote **`this.Hide()`** instead of `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;`.

Comment: Same thing, hiding the owner of the dialog also forces it to close.

Comment: @Fred as I started reading the comments of @Hans Passant in regard to the question, I also came to the conclusion that this will be the only solution. It works like a charm, except that when the parent hides, the taskbar icon disappears and I need to locate the child hovering in the bottom left to restore the icon when the parent shows. I've tried setting and unsetting the `ShowInTaskbar` of the child in the menioned handler, but this resolves to the windows entirely gone and no taskbar icon for anything in ALT+Tab. Have to kill the exe or stop debugging

Comment: @Fred Yet I see that `Show(IWin32Window)` is entirely not the same as `ShowDialog(IWin32Window)` in the most basic and needed (also reason why used) way. When the Show is called, it does not centre parent at all, where ShowDialog does and ShowDialog prevents working on the parent while the child is displayed. This was the desired outcome of the call to ShowDialog